# How to sum values by groups in sequence

Tags: r, sum, grouping

I have a dataframe with duration values in column `duration` and group values in column `gaze_focus`.

```
df1
   duration gaze_focus
29    1.011  periphery
31    1.590     center
33    1.582     center
35    0.571  periphery
37    0.561     center
39    2.136     center
41    0.181  periphery
43    1.475     center
45    0.177  periphery
47    0.940  periphery
49    2.102     center
```

I'd like to compute the sums of **immediately adjacent identical group values** to obtain this result:

```
df2
  duration gaze_focus
1    1.011  periphery
2    3.172     center
3    0.571  periphery
4    2.697     center
5    0.181  periphery
6    1.475     center
7    1.117  periphery
8    2.102     center
```

I know that mathematical operations such as summing by group can be done using e.g. `aggregate`or `tapply` but I don't know how to sum values by groups in little chunks. Help is appreciated!

Reproducible data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(duration = c(1.011, 1.59, 1.582, 0.571, 0.561, 
2.136, 0.181, 1.475, 0.177, 0.94, 2.102), gaze_focus = c("periphery", 
"center", "center", "periphery", "center", "center", "periphery", 
"center", "periphery", "periphery", "center")), row.names = c(29L, 
31L, 33L, 35L, 37L, 39L, 41L, 43L, 45L, 47L, 49L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
df1 %>%
 group_by(gaze_focus, rleid = with(rle(gaze_focus), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))) %>%
 summarise_all(sum) %>%
 arrange(rleid)

  gaze_focus rleid duration
  <chr>      <int>    <dbl>
1 periphery      1    1.01 
2 center         2    3.17 
3 periphery      3    0.571
4 center         4    2.70 
5 periphery      5    0.181
6 center         6    1.48 
7 periphery      7    1.12 
8 center         8    2.10
```

Comment: is it a reason why you use `seq_along` instead of just `seq`?

Comment: @AlexB it may be slightly more efficient as it was specifically created for this task.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work:

```
> for(i in 1:(nrow(df1)-1)){
+           if(df1$gaze_focus[i] == df1$gaze_focus[i+1]) { 
+             df1$duration[i+1] = df1$duration[i] + df1$duration[i+1] 
+             df1[i,] = NA
+             }
+   else{ df1$duration[i] = df1$duration[i] }
+ }
> df1
   duration gaze_focus
29    1.011  periphery
31       NA       <NA>
33    3.172     center
35    0.571  periphery
37       NA       <NA>
39    2.697     center
41    0.181  periphery
43    1.475     center
45       NA       <NA>
47    1.117  periphery
49    2.102     center
> df2 <- df1 %>% na.omit()
> df2
   duration gaze_focus
29    1.011  periphery
33    3.172     center
35    0.571  periphery
39    2.697     center
41    0.181  periphery
43    1.475     center
47    1.117  periphery
49    2.102     center
> rownames(df2) <- NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

An option with `dplyr` and `rleid`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(grp = rleid(gaze_focus), gaze_focus) %>% 
  summarise(duration = sum(duration, na.rm = TRUE),
         .groups = 'drop') %>% 
  select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 2
#  gaze_focus duration
#  <chr>         <dbl>
#1 periphery     1.01 
#2 center        3.17 
#3 periphery     0.571
#4 center        2.70 
#5 periphery     0.181
#6 center        1.48 
#7 periphery     1.12 
#8 center        2.10
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table` to create every consecutive values as separate group.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)[, .(gaze_focus = first(gaze_focus), 
               duration = sum(duration)), rleid(gaze_focus)]

#   rleid gaze_focus duration
#1:     1  periphery    1.011
#2:     2     center    3.172
#3:     3  periphery    0.571
#4:     4     center    2.697
#5:     5  periphery    0.181
#6:     6     center    1.475
#7:     7  periphery    1.117
#8:     8     center    2.102
```